# Linearization of the ODE system: Problems

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, nonlinear, control-systems

I have summarized the issues covered in the topics:

[Linearization of ODE without an equilibrium](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253133/linearization-of-ode-without-an-equilibrium)

[I ask for help with commands TransferFunctionModel + StateSpaceModel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253144/i-ask-for-help-with-commands-transferfunctionmodel-statespacemodel)

[Plot3D + WhenEvent + NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253092/plot3d-whenevent-ndsolve)

---

**Problem:**

*Given the ODE system:*

```
Clear["Derivative"]; ClearAll["Global`*"];

pars = {\[Alpha] = 1, \[Omega] = 2 Pi 2};

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{s''[t] + \[Omega]^2 s[t] == 0, x'[t] == G[t] + u[t], z'[t] + z[t] == D[-(x[t] + s[t] - 1)^2, t], G'[t] + G[t] == z[t] s[t]}, {{s[t], 0}, {s'[t], \[Alpha] \[Omega]}, {x[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}, {G[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x[t], s[t], z[t], G[t]}, t];
```

---

*Calculating the required output signal:*

```
or = OutputResponse[asys, 0, {t, 0, 25}];

Plot[{or[[1]], 1}, {t, 0, 15}, PlotRange -> Full];
```

[image]

*If we do not take small oscillations (we do not need them) contained in the trajectory, then it is clear that this oscillatory transient process can be roughly described by a quasilinear law, which means that a certain transfer function corresponds to it.*

---

*Drawing on ideas from:*

[Linearization of a nonlinear system](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138852/linearization-of-a-nonlinear-system)

*As well as:*

[System of ODE $\rightarrow$ Affine State-Space $\rightarrow$ System of ODE in Cauchy form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246111/system-of-ode-rightarrow-affine-state-space-rightarrow-system-of-ode-in-ca)

*I am trying to linearize the system at the equilibrium point using the Jacobi matrix. For some reason, one of the balance points is not searched for, so I set it manually:*

```
ClearAll[stateEqs]; stateEqs[Verbatim[AffineStateSpaceModel][{a_, b_, c_, d_}, x0_, u0_, y_, t_]] := Module[{u, x}, x = Replace[x0, {xx_, x1_} :> xx, 1]; u = Replace[u0, {uu_, u1_} :> uu, 1]; D[x, t] == a + b.u];
 
newode = asys // stateEqs // Thread; newode // ExpandAll // MapAt[Simplify, #, {All, 2}] & // Column // Expand;


eqns = ReplaceAll[newode /. Thread[Array[Subscript[\[FormalX], #] &, 5] -> {ds, s, x, z, G}] // DeleteCases[True], u[t] -> 0] // Expand;

eq = Solve[{s[t], -16 \[Pi]^2 ds[t], G[t], 2 G[t] - 2 ds[t] G[t] + 2 s[t] - 2 ds[t] s[t] - 2 G[t] x[t] - 2 s[t] x[t] - z[t], -G[t] + ds[t] z[t]} == {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]}, Reals] // Simplify; (*Equilibrium Points*)

eq = {{ds[t] -> 0, s[t] -> 0, x[t] -> 0, z[t] -> 0, G[t] -> 0}}(*Handly equilibrium point*)
```

---

*Here I calculate the Jacobi matrix:*

```
j = D[{s[t], -16 \[Pi]^2 ds[t], G[t], 2 G[t] - 2 ds[t] G[t] + 2 s[t] - 2 ds[t] s[t] - 2 G[t] x[t] - 2 s[t] x[t] - z[t], -G[t] + ds[t] z[t]}, {{ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]}}];(*Jacobi Matrix*)

J = N[j /. eq[[1]]] // Simplify;

eqns = Thread[{ds'[t], s'[t], x'[t], z'[t], G'[t]} == J.{ds[t], s[t], x[t], z[t], G[t]} + {0, 0, u[t], 0, 0}];(*Collect ODE's*)

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[eqns, {{s[t], 0}, {s'[t], \[Alpha] \[Omega]}, {x[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}, {G[t], 0}}, {u[t]}, {x[t]}, t](*Linearized Affine State-Space*)
```

---

*When calculating the output of a "linearized" system, I get sheer nonsense. Either I made a mistake in determining the stationary point, or something else.*

```
or2 = OutputResponse[asys, 0, {t, 0, 25}];

Plot[{or2}, {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 200];
```

[image]

### Dear specialists.With all the obvious similarity of the transient processes in the original system, my attempts to describe it with a linear state-space repeatedly fail. Help me figure out this problem. Topic will be useful to others, and also give me a powerful impetus to understand the problem and master the tools. I would be grateful to everyone for help and advice .

Comment: Your initial conditions coincide with the equilibrium point, that's why you get that graph. Change, for example, from 0 to 0.1 and you will see what you are looking for.

Comment: The change should be in (*Linearized Affine State-Space*), before or2 and Plot[].

Comment: @E.Chan-López Thank you for the answer. I discovered this oversight when I figured it out myself. Anyway, the problem remains - the discrepancy is too big. Something is wrong.

Comment: It is true, the discrepancy is too big. I will review it in detail and if I see something I will let you know.

Comment: @E.Chan-López I'll give you a little hint, something that I groped for myself, but haven't figured it out yet. I have a guess that something is happening when differentiating in the equation $\dot{z}+z=\frac{d}{dt}(-(x+s+1)^2)$. The constant component of the signal is lost. It is possible that it needs to be specified as an input signal. And second, the variable $s$ appears like as an oscillatory signal. It is quite possible that somewhere there are quadratic components $s^2$ of this signal, which can be averaged over the period of this signal.

Comment: @E.Chan-López it becomes much easier if we assume an equation,  $\begin{cases} \ddot{s}+\omega^2 \cdot s=0 \\ \dot{x}=G+u \\ \dot{G}+G=(-(x+s-1)^2) \cdot s \\  \end{cases}$ but the variable $z$ is needed. It cannot be ruled out.